# Extjs GridFilter feature don't work

Tags: javascript, extjs, filter, extjs4

I'm working in a Ruby On Rails + Ext js app.. and I'm trying to show a grid with the filter feature but I can't I've been reading a lot of post and even the Sencha example page but I can't make it work.

Here is the live code.. a simple grid without the gridpanel working https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3fh

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true});
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', '../ux');
Ext.require([
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature',
    'Ext.toolbar.Paging'
]);



var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {

   fields: [
           {name: 'tipo', type: 'string'},
           {name: 'concepto', type: 'string'},
           {name: 'ingreso', type: 'int'},
           {name: 'egreso', type: 'int'},
           {name: 'por_alicuota', type: 'float'},
           {name: 'fecha', type: 'string', dateFormat:'m/Y'}
       ] ,     

   data: [
{tipo:'Fijo',concepto:'Ingresos por Cuotas',ingreso:345000,egreso:0,por_alicuota:0,fecha:'11/2013'},
{tipo:'Extra',concepto:'Ingresos por Sanciones',ingreso:24500,egreso:0,por_alicuota:0,fecha:'11/2013'}

          ],

})

var filtersCfg = {
        ftype: 'filters',
        local: true,
        filters: [{
                type: 'string',
                dataIndex: 'tipo'
            }, {
                type: 'string',
                dataIndex: 'concepto'
            }]
    };

var grid =   Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getElementById("leftPanel"),
        store: store,
        height: 300,
        filters : [filtersCfg],
        title: "grid view",

        columns: [
             {
                text: 'Pay',
                sortable: true,
                filterable: true,
                dataIndex: 'tipo'
            },
            {
                text: 'Concept',
                sortable: true,
                filterable: true,
                dataIndex: 'concepto',                    
            }]

});

Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.QuickTips.init();


    grid.render('content');
    grid.show();
});
```

Hope you guys can help me!

Comment: I'm currently looking for the issue. Meanwhile, you may try to parse this demo : http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/example/grid-filtering/grid-filter-local.html.

Comment: I've been looking that code but still don't make it work =( @wared

Comment: I've found a difference in the grid's config, I think that `filters: [filtersCfg],` should be `features: [filtersCfg],`. However, there is a type error somewhere which might not be related to the filters... See the console.

Comment: Additionally, there is an extra comma in the second column's definition which could lead to a crash in some browsers (IE) : `dataIndex: 'concepto',`.

Comment: I've removed all code related to the filters and the type error vanishes. There might be something missing either in the filters definition, or in the required files.

Comment: when I chaged filter into features..the console displays "TypeError: c is not a constructor" @wared

Comment: Read my comments please. Well, I wonder if the loader actually works, indeed, removing the corresponding lines produces no error... Then, inspecting the DOM I can't see any file related to the filters.

Comment: Furthermore, I do not see any attempt to load these files in the network panel. I was hoping to find some 404 errors.

Comment: I've tested in the proyect and the Loader works... you are right It was just change filters: [filtersCfg] into features: [filtersCfg] @wared

Comment: So, the issue comes from the combination between the loader and the fiddle context right?

Comment: right! @wared it was just the fiddle context! now it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `filters: [filtersCfg],` with `features: [filtersCfg],`, and remove this extra comma in `dataIndex: 'concepto',` which is likely to crash IE. It's important to note that the ExtJS file loader seems not to work in this fiddle (Type Error).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Wared for the Answer... The only thing to change in the original code is :

```
filters: [filtersCfg]
```

INTO `features: [filtersCfg]` now the code looks like:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true});
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', '../ux');
Ext.require([
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature',
    'Ext.toolbar.Paging'
]);



var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {

   fields: [
           {name: 'tipo', type: 'string'},
           {name: 'concepto', type: 'string'},
           {name: 'ingreso', type: 'int'},
           {name: 'egreso', type: 'int'},
           {name: 'por_alicuota', type: 'float'},
           {name: 'fecha', type: 'string', dateFormat:'m/Y'}
       ] ,     

   data: [
{tipo:'Fijo',concepto:'Ingresos por Cuotas',ingreso:345000,egreso:0,por_alicuota:0,fecha:'11/2013'},
{tipo:'Extra',concepto:'Ingresos por Sanciones',ingreso:24500,egreso:0,por_alicuota:0,fecha:'11/2013'}

          ],

})

var filtersCfg = {
        ftype: 'filters',
        local: true,
        filters: [{
                type: 'string',
                dataIndex: 'tipo'
            }, {
                type: 'string',
                dataIndex: 'concepto'
            }]
    };

var grid =   Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getElementById("leftPanel"),
        store: store,
        height: 300,
        features : [filtersCfg],
        title: "grid view",

        columns: [
             {
                text: 'Pay',
                sortable: true,
                filterable: true,
                dataIndex: 'tipo'
            },
            {
                text: 'Concept',
                sortable: true,
                filterable: true,
                dataIndex: 'concepto',                    
            }]

});

Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.QuickTips.init();


    grid.render('content');
    grid.show();
});
```